# instance vs. method as argument -- understanding lifetime and garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

In a contrived example, I have an instance supporting the following interface:

```
public interface ISelector<L, R>
{
    R Select(L value);
}
```

Now, I consider 2 ways of calling `IEnumerable.Select<L, R>(Func<L, R>)`:

```
IEnumerable<L> l;
ISelector<L, R> selector;
IEnumerable<R> r;
r = l.Select(v => selector.Select(v)); // 1
r = l.Select(selector.Select); // 2
```

Way 1 captures the reference to the selector from the variable into a closure, and this closure will hold this reference independently of the scope of the variable `selector`. So the variable `selector` may go out of scope and `r.ToList()` may be called after variable `selector` went out of scope.

However, I am unsure of how to understand way 2: How is `ISelector<L, R>.Select` assigned and captured? And may the variable `selector` go out of scope and may `r.ToList()` be called after variable `selector` went out of scope?

Readability-wise I prefer way 2, yet before using it, I would like to understand the lifetime of the captured and garbage-collected parts first.

Comment: You already have a "contrived example". What stops you from making it a working example? (Or non-working if it doesn't)

Comment: You might find it instructive to look at the CIL produced either way

Comment: One of the main reasons for working with a garbage collected language is so that you *don't have to worry about lifetimes* most of the time. Yes, if you have a *specific* example that, using a profiler, demonstrates a lifetime is too long, dig into the details. But don't spend time trying to micromanage lifetimes.

Comment: Well, this was my first C# question. Fildor, I knew both ways work. Though, with way 2 I wnted to understand how. Aakash, indeed, and luckily Marc showed me a way how to do that. Damien, just understanding, no micromanaging. Yet, having grown up in a not garbage-collected language and getting to know long-term C# devs' code bases, I still sometimes would like to read when they're done using something instead of so much allocate-and-forget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second example, `selector.Select` is interpreted as shorthand for a new delegate instance where `selector` is the target and `ISelector<L, R>.Select` is the `MethodInfo`. As such, `selector` is reachable via the delegate instance, so: as long as the delegate is reachable, the object of `selector` is reachable, and cannot be collected. So yes, you can call `ToList()` safely at any time.

Specifically, [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANmgExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChyAGAAnOpQG4Hm3qA6ADLYAdgEdu9HpRYANFgG8GLFS2Wr2rAMoxcMMBgAUojC2wBKFgF4AfGf4AVCFoxRRAc0PnJqvkj4AzAA8JnYA4jAYWhAArlBgMF7WdiIxuLg+6irs/uQoLABiEBBeWYplvgBuAIZQLBDAAFbWLCIwAO5yXj6+GtTBoSy4LRFRsfGJ3hWqNXUADlAQjfoYMAQtuPw6egaGDY1buitT9L2qYQDC/ADSMDBzAIK42JWJC0sraye+AL4MP0A=), we see for `var projected l.Select(obj.Select);`

```
// l. [push 1]
IL_000d: ldloc.1 
// obj. [push 1]
IL_000e: ldloc.0 
// Select [push 1]
IL_000f: ldftn instance string X::Select(int32) 
// new Func<int,string>([pop 2, push 1])
IL_0015: newobj instance void class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Func`2<int32, string>::.ctor(object, native int)
// Enumerable.Select<int,string>([pop 2, push 1])
IL_001a: call class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!1> [System.Linq]System.Linq.Enumerable::Select<int32, string>(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)
// projected=[pop 1]
IL_001f: stloc.2
```

which is the delegate

Comment: "`selector.Select` is interpreted as a shorthand for a new delegate instance (...)" was the key information. And thank you for the IL!